# How to get an Apple developer certificate for a PhoneGap app?

Tags: ios, iphone, windows, certificate, phonegap-build

I've successfully used PhoneGap Build to build a PhoneGap app that works fine on Android devices, however, I also want to install the app on iPhones as well.

Whenever I build the app via PhoneGap Build, I get the following error for the iOS build:

```
You must provide a signing key, first. Find out how to fix this.
```

And if I click on the link in the error message, I go to the following page:
http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/signing_signing-ios.md.html

Part of the process requires an Apple iPhone developer certificate file provided by Apple. I have searched quite a bit on how to do this and I have yet to get a clear answer. In other words, I don't know what to do.

So my question is: How do I get an Apple iPhone developer certificate file? Can someone please explain the process in simple English? Thank you.

By the way, I'm using a Windows PC and do not have access to an Apple computer with Mac OS.

Comment: You need to join the Apple developer program and pay an annual program membership fee and you will need a Mac to perform the signing operation: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.3.0/signing_signing-ios.md.html

Comment: Paulw11, thanks for the link. I followed that link to a ton of other links which finally led me to https://developer.apple.com/programs/enroll/. It was super hard to find though. I was only able to do it by using `Ctrl + F` and guessing certain keywords. Apple is really horrible about all of this! And even once I was "fortunate" enough to find the enrollment page, I saw that it's $99/year and like you said, I have to have a Mac to actually do the signing operation. Guess I'll be sticking with just Android for now. If I ever get enough business, I might sign up. Either way though, Apple sucks!

Comment: It isn't that hard; http://developer.apple.com "Program" on the menu at the top, big blue "Enrol" button at the top of the Program page

Comment: Good point. I didn't get there that way. Either way, it wasn't obvious, and I really don't like all these barriers for entry that Apple creates.

Comment: Have a look at services like http://www.macincloud.com

Comment: That would probably solve that problem. Thanks.